# How to compare date(different format) from a list of Variables in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, azure-databricks

I need to extract the string variable with latest timestamp from a list.

The variables are in below format:
|Name|
|:---|
|First_Record2022-10-11_NameofRecord.txt|
|Second_Record_20221017.txt|

for now, i am fetching this in a list and iterating in a for loop to get the latest date from the two records using below line of code:

````
 ```python
  for index,rows in df.iterrows:
    datestr=rows['name'].replace('-','')
    datestr=re.search(r'\d{8}|\d{6}',datestr).group()    
    date=DT.datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y%m%d')   
    print('{:23}-->{}'.format(rows['name'],date))```
````

But this is only giving me date back. How do i compare the two strings and find out the string with latest date as in while comparing these two variables - "First_Record2022-10-11_NameofRecord.txt" and "Second_Record_20221017.txt ", i should be able to get "Second_Record_20221017.txt " as result.

Comment: added answer, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC , is that what you're looking for?

```
df['date']= df['Name'].str.extract(r'(\d{4}.*?(?=[_|\.]))').replace(r'-','',regex=True)
df.sort_values('date').tail(1)['Name'].squeeze()
```

```
'Second_Record_20221017.txt'
```

Comment: Hi Naveed, i am looking to fetch string with latest timestamp... so while comparing these two variables - "First_Record2022-10-11_NameofRecord.txt" and "Second_Record_20221017.txt ", i should be able to get "Second_Record_20221017.txt " as result.

Comment: Hi  @Naveed, i tried above script with different data but it is only fetching the last value of the list...

Comment: the solution is limited to what you described in the question. You needed the max-date and that is what it gets to you.

Comment: i created a dataframe,
```df=pd.Dataframe({'name':['spam2022-10-22','spammed_20221017','spammer20220710']})```
and tested this with above code
but i am only getting last value as in 'spammer20220710'

Comment: there isn't any character after these names? like in your question, you had.txt etc there

Comment: sorry Naveed, my bad!! the solution works....Thanks a ton!! :)